# Bootstrap panel-primary overflow-x scrolling background color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

This is a css question on a bootstrap panel. If you open my jsfiddle below and adjust the display so the overflow-x is activated, you'll see the blue background color of the bootstrap panel-heading transitions to white rather than keeping the blue. What is needed to retain the blue when overflow-x is activated?

CSS:

```
  .panel-primary {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x:scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row form-group">
<div class="panel panel-primary">
<div id="hpanel" class="panel-heading">Heading</div>
<div class="panel-body">
  <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Col1</th>
        <th>Col2</th>
        <th>Col3</th>
        <th>Col4</th>
        <th>Col5</th>
        <th>Col6</th>
        <th>Col7</th>
        <th>Col8</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td>some data</td>
       <td>some data</td>
       <td>some data</td>
       <td>some data</td>
       <td>some data</td>
       <td>some data</td>
       <td>some data</td>
       <td>some data</td>

     </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</div> 
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {

    } );
} );
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lecleard/62zrL7p1/)

Thanks

Comment: I'm seeing the `panel-heading` with blue background, not the `.panel-primary`

Comment: You're right Yuri.  However, I wanted the scrolling on the .panel-primary as it would look odd with it set on the .panel-heading.  However, I have since come up with a solution making the table inside the panel responsive instead.

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question after playing around with several things.  I created a div around the table.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
   <table>
   .....
   </table>
</div>
```

This makes the table data responsive rather than the panel and resolves the color issue and probably better way to go about things anyway.  I have updated my original fiddle with the updated code.

Thanks